# How can I grab the last N elements in a Map<int, dynamic>?

Tags: dart

I currently have a `Map<int, dynamic>` where the key is an order of insertion.

For example

```
const Map<int, dynamic> log = {
  1: {'startDate': 1111, 'endDate': 2222},
  2: {'startDate': 123123, 'endDate': 1231233},
  3: {'startDate': 555555, 'endDate': 5555556},
  4: {'startDate': 888888},
};
```

**Now how can I get the last X amount?**

I was thinking of

```
final Iterable<int> numberOfLogs = log.keys;
final Iterable<int> reversedNumberOfLogs = numberOfLogs.toList().reversed;
final Iterable<int> recent2Logs = reversedNumberOfLogs.take(2);
```

And then I could loop through the `recent2Logs` and then access the `log` Map by the looped index?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that `Map`'s and `Set`'s default implementations are a `LinkedHashMap` and `LinkedHashSet` respectively, which already preserve insertion order for you when iterating over them.  Taking advantage of that, to get an `Iterable` of the last *n* values, you can do:

```dart
var lastValues = log.values.toList().reversed.take(n);
```

If you want the result to stay a `Map` with integer keys, then that'd be:

```dart
var prunedLog = Map.fromEntries(log.entries.toList().reversed.take(n));
```

Note that both examples above will return items in most-recent to least-recent order.  If you want them in chronological order, you'd have to reverse the result again, e.g.:

```dart
var prunedLog = Map.fromEntries(
  log.entries.toList().reversed.take(n).toList().reversed);
```

Comment: Woah! This is way better than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do

```
final recent2Logs = log.keys.toList().getRange(log.length - 2, log.length));
```